# Engine Matlab issues

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, matlab-engine

I am triyng to implement Matlab in a c++ program. http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sjeh3/wii/ 
The application is using gtk a wii mote lib and the Matlab Camera Calibration Toolbox (http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/ ). it works perfectly.
I want to use matlab ploting tools to build a graphic provided by the application. But i am having issues building the app with matlab engine .

In the main.cpp i just added the code from the matlab example engdemo.cpp in the main function and included engine.h and mex.h.
Even with the examples like engdemo.cpp i always have this error :

mex: link of ' "...mexa64"' failed.

here are the console views:

```
    root@ubuntu:/home/hugo/Bureau/sjeh3-wii/wmgui# ./build2
----------------------------------------------------------------
-> mbuildopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $HOME/.matlab/$REL_VERSION)
   FILE = /root/.matlab/R2009b/mbuildopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    TMW_ROOT              = /home/hugo/Matlab
->    CC                    = g++-4.1
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include/cpp -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -DUNIX -DX11 -DGLNXA64 -DGCC -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/runtime/glnxa64  -lmwmclmcrrt -lm
         arguments          = 
->    LD                    = g++-4.1
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         arguments          =  -L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include/cpp -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -DUNIX -DX11 -DGLNXA64 -DGCC -pthread  -g  "main.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include/cpp -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -DUNIX -DX11 -DGLNXA64 -DGCC -pthread  -g  "interface.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include/cpp -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -DUNIX -DX11 -DGLNXA64 -DGCC -pthread  -g  "support.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -g -pthread  -L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox -o wmgui  main.o interface.o support.o -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/runtime/glnxa64  -lmwmclmcrrt -lm  -lcalib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid

main.o: In function `main':
/home/hugo/Bureau/sjeh3-wii/wmgui/main.cpp:363: undefined reference to `engOpen'
/home/hugo/Bureau/sjeh3-wii/wmgui/main.cpp:367: undefined reference to `engEvalString'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mbuild: link of 'wmgui' failed.

root@ubuntu:/home/hugo/Bureau/sjeh3-wii/wmgui# ./build2
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $HOME/.matlab/$REL_VERSION)
   FILE = /root/.matlab/R2009b/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /home/hugo/Matlab
->    CC                    = gcc-4.1
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = g++-4.1
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = g95
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = g++-4.1
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64
         arguments          =  -lang cpp -L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -lcalib -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         arguments          =  -lang cpp -L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -lcalib -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -g  "main.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -g  "interface.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -c  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -g  "support.cpp"

-> g++-4.1 -g -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o  "wmgui.mexa64"  main.o interface.o support.o  -lang cpp -L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -lcalib -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm

g++-4.1: cpp: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

    mex: link of ' "wmgui.mexa64"' failed.


#!/bin/sh
(mex or mbuild) -v -g -output wmgui main.cpp interface.cpp support.cpp -lang cpp \
-L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -lcalib -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox \
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include  -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64
```

I forgot to say that i wanted to use Matlab engine and not my c++ application in matlab. maybe it wasn't so clear. I don't think the program will work as a mex-file.

Sincerely,
Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found my issue. i was compiling my application using mexopts.sh conf and not engopts.sh
After the succeful compilation i had the Error Can't start Matlab engine. i just apt-get install csh. and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your linux build command is broken. the compiler is missing some paths to some library.

```
    #!/bin/sh
(mex or mbuild) -v -g -output wmgui main.cpp interface.cpp support.cpp -lang cpp \
-L/usr/lib/ -L../toolbox -L../libcwiid -lcalib -L../libcwiid -L/opt/gnome/lib64 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lglitz -lm -lpng12 -lXrender -lX11 -lpthread -lXau -lXdmcp -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lcwiid -L/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -L../../matlablibtest/toolbox \
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/gnome/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include  -I../libcwiid -I../toolbox -I/opt/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/lib -I/home/hugo/Matlab/extern/include -I/home/hugo/Matlab/bin/glnxa64
```

Normaly you should find your anwser in this line code !

Sincerely
Hugo