# Calling matlab from C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-engine

I tried to call matlab from a .cpp file. I used the following command to compile 
`engdemo.cpp` which includes `"engine.h"`

```
g++ engdemo.cpp -I/usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/include -L/usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib -o engdemo
```

What I got is the following:

```
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `engOpen'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `mxGetPr'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `engPutVariable'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x189): undefined reference to `engEvalString'
```

...

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

---

I guess it might be some link problem but I am not sure. Please help me out. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319943/engine-matlab-issues/3909572#3909572

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [what @Kurt S said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757613/calling-matlab-from-c/7757678#7757678), you'll need to include libraries.  These are common ones you'll need:  libeng.lib libmat.lib libmx.lib, but you might need others.

Thus you want to add the linking options `-llibeng -llibmat -llibmx`

But you might need others as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried all these three linking options, and I got all similar results

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibeng
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I find all the linking options?

Comment: You also need to set the lib path to where these .lib files exist with the `-L` option

Comment: Thanks. I guess the matlab I installed was probably incomplete. I need to download all the missing packages first. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Because I cannot find any .lib files. The lib folder has almost nothing.

Comment: That's surprising.  Did you do a search for `libeng.lib` with something like the search option in Windows or with `find -name libeng.lib` in Unix/Linux?

Comment: I tried "find ", and it doesn't find anything. That's why I feel that the installation is not complete.

Comment: This is a really old thread, but for other people with this problem, on a Linux OS, you should be searching for libeng.so, not libeng.lib.  See this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple makefile to help you get started:

#### Makefile

```
# root directory of MATLAB installation
MATLABROOT="/usr/local/matlabR2010a"

all: engdemo

engdemo:
    g++ ${MATLABROOT}/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp -o engdemo \
        -I${MATLABROOT}/extern/include \
        -L${MATLABROOT}/extern/lib -llibeng -llibmx

clean:
    rm -f engdemo *.o
```

Simply use it by calling `make`, then running the program as `./engdemo`

---

You can also compile this directly from inside MATLAB. First make sure you have run `mbuild -setup` command at least once:

```
>> srcFile = fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','eng_mat','engdemo.cpp');
>> mbuild(srcFile, '-llibeng','-llibmx')
>> !engdemo
```

Comment: Amro, thank you very much for your post. I tried both ways, while it seems there are still problems.
For the first one, calling make, I got this 

"makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: For the second, it says 

"/usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp:113: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibeng
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mbuild: link of 'engdemo' failed.
??? Error using ==> mbuild at 193
Unable to complete successfully."

Comment: @lamothy: Makefiles require a leading tab (`\t`) not spaces (`  `) to start the action clause. If you copy/pasted from the above, SO might have formatted all tabs as spaces..

Comment: I see. You are definitely right. Now what I got is the following 
"-I"/usr/local/matlabR2010a"/extern/include \
 -L"/usr/local/matlabR2010a"/extern/lib -llibeng -llibmx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibeng
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [engdemo] Error 1"

Comment: @lamothy: you could have a broken installation, maybe you should reinstall MATLAB

Answer (score 1):

The problem is improper specification of include files and folders (i.e. for libraries and link files) and a few additional dependencies.

You can make use of a simple demo code for the interfacing C/C++ and MATLAB is given [here](http://preetisblog.com/programming/use-matlab-from-c-and-c-plus-plus/), so as to understand what needs to be done.

Also you need to use a CMAKELISTS.TXT file with suitable settings for MATLAB, for which a good tutorial is available [here](http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it which libraries to link against with the **-l** option to g++. Based on your link line, the library should be in **/usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib**. As an example, if the library you need is called **libmatlab.a** you need to to add the `-lmatlab` option to the command line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm sorry that I'm not sure the name of the library. In the  /usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib folder, I found a several files ended with .map. For example MexLibrary.map. What should I add to the command line?

Comment: @lamothy: If you don't know what the files are, how are we to?!

Comment: Hi Tomalak,
I know my questions are naive. I am a beginner and try to find some help here.